# filtered tags seems to no longer work

Tags: support, tags, filtering

I have some browser bookmarks to a few filtered-tag queries. These now all show ***no matches*** ("No questions found."), but if I put the tag(s) in the search bar and query there are plenty of hits.  This is the case for Google Chrome as well as IE8, at least.

For instance, this filter: https://stackexchange.com/filters/110094/lisp.

---

I stumbled on this workaround: I start to create a new filter, defining it the same way as one of my existing filters, and I hit `Preview`.  Then I can go back to choosing the previously defined filter, and it works.

But I apparently need to use that workaround separately for each filter that I have. It is not enough to do it for one filter, in order to fix things for all of the filters.

Am I missing something? Thx.

Comment: You broke it...no, I did repro in IE11/Win7, On firefox as well. Looks like the no answers tab stays empty for sure for SO. For other sites filtwrs seems to work. Some of us see other glitches around the network so that might be causing this.

Comment: FWIW, I saw the problems on other sites, not SO. E.g., Super User and Stack Exchange itself. Anyway, it seems to be fixed now.

Comment: It was a network wide hick-up/update/fall-over thingy. All sites were affected.